# What does the dist attribute of the kamada_kawai_layout in networkx mean and how can I use that attribute to control the spacing of my graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph generated from networkx. I want to control the spacing in the graph, and specifically in the kamada_kawai_layout display.

I attach an image of the graph here:

[image: Graph]

If you see, there are multiple nodes going out of `independent_5` and `dependent_1_result`. However they're all placed on top of each other and I would like them to be separated and distinct so we can actually see the different paths.

The [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.kamada_kawai_layout.html) on the layout describes the dist attribute as: "`dist (float (default=None))` – A two-level dictionary of optimal distances between nodes, indexed by source and destination node. If `None`, the distance is computed using `shortest_path_length()`."

So I get that we need to supply a dictionary to control the spacing, but I don't get the details of how we would do that. Is the key tuple? And what would the value look like — would it be a number? What would this number mean? etc? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello! I know I am super late to this question but did you manage to get an answer on this? If so, could you please add it as an answer below? I am trying to figure the same thing out in terms of spacing between connected nodes.

Comment: Hey, no I haven't. Will update here if I do find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The function expects a dictionary of the form `dist['source']['target'] = distance`.

As you can see [in the code](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/4c5a033185f2fb2c692330bad7a7a47c95b3e5e5/networkx/drawing/layout.py#L696), if `dist` is omitted the function takes the result of `dict(nx.shortest_path_length(G, weight=weight))`. `shortest_path_length` returns an iterator over pairs `(source, distances)`, where `distances` is a dict mapping target nodes to distances.

Note that the function **does not assume distances to be symmetric**! If you define only the distance from `'u'` to `'v'` to be `100.0` (i.e. only `dist['u']['v'] = 100.0`), the distance from `'v'` to `'u'` is assumed to be `1000000` (see definition of `dist_mtx` in [the definition of the function](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/4c5a033185f2fb2c692330bad7a7a47c95b3e5e5/networkx/drawing/layout.py#L696)).